# Apply some functions on a struct owning those functions

Tags: iterator, rust, lifetime

I want to apply some functions on a struct owning those functions.

First try:

```
struct VM {
    buffer: Vec<fn(&mut VM)>,
    stack: Vec<isize>,
}

impl VM {
    fn new() -> VM {
        VM {
            buffer: vec![VM::op_zero, VM::op_drop],
            stack: vec![],
        }
    }
    fn op_zero(&mut self) { self.stack.push(0); }
    fn op_drop(&mut self) {
        match self.stack.pop() {
            Some(i) => println!("drop {}", i),
            None => println!("stack underflow!")
        }
    }
    fn evaluate(&mut self) {
        for op in self.buffer {
            op(self);
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut vm = VM::new();
    vm.evaluate();
}
```

This doesn't work because of moving out of borrowed content. I added an `&` before `self.buffer`, but it still doesn't work because `self.buffer` is also borrowed as immutable.

```
fn evaluate(&mut self) {
    for op in &self.buffer {
        op(self);
    }
}
```

Third try works, but has the overhead of runtime bounds checking on array indexing:

```
fn evaluate(&mut self) {
    let len = self.buffer.len();
    for i in 0..len {
        let op = self.buffer[i];
        op(self);
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to work around the borrow checker?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to pass `self` to `op`s if they don't use `self`, and how they might use `self` changes whether this is even safe. I feel your example's lacking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't really be trying to "work around the borrow checker".  It's preventing you from doing this because there's no guarantee that the `op`s you invoke won't mess with the buffer you're trying to iterate over.  In fact, your final code has the same problem: an `op` could *truncate* the buffer, leading to a panic when you try to read past the end of the vector.

One way to do it safely would be to swap out the `buffer` when you evaluate it.  Assuming you don't intend to evaluate the same sequence of instructions more than once:

```rust
fn evaluate(&mut self) {
    use std::mem;
    for op in mem::replace(&mut self.buffer, vec![]) {
        op(self);
    }
}
```

In this case, the new buffer can be modified by the invoked `op`s without interfering with `evaluate`.

Comment: *Assuming you don't intend to evaluate the same sequence of instructions more than once* — you can always `replace` the original vector after you are done iterating, restoring the object to the original state.

Comment: @Shepmaster Aye, but the question *then* becomes: what happens if the ops added ops to the now empty buffer?  Do you append those?  Preprend them?  Discard them?  I didn't feel like confusing the issue at the time.  :P

Comment: Oh, absolutely. I know *you* knew you could put it back, I just wanted to make sure future readers realized it too!